# how can I set up ssh acces to remte bare repository for admin?

Tags: git, centos7, remote-repository

On a VPS I can login using

```
ssh admin@server.com
```

I have created a bare repository in:

```
/var/repo/site.git
```

which has:

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  119 Jan 31 13:35 site.git
```

Locally I set up:

git remote add production ssh://admin@server.com/../../var/repo/site.git

But when I try tyo push I get this error:

```
PS D:\path\site-directory> git push production master
admin@server.com's password: 
Enumerating objects: 1152, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1152/1152), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1073/1073), done.
remote: fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/var/repo/site.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To ssh://server.com/../../var/repo/site.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://server.com/../../var/repo/site.git'
```

I think that I have to adjust some permissions, or I may have set up the wrong path.

Can anyone help me figure out how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Yeah, it's a permissions problem. The directory is not owned by admin or marked world-writeable. What are your goals here? Do you want a single user, 'admin' to be able to push this repository, or do you want to let multiple users push it? That's going to change what kind of solution is suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your amswer. I want just the admin to be able to push.

Answer (score 1):

This directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  119 Jan 31 13:35 site.git
```

Has a user ownership set to root. Since admin is not the owner of the directory, Linux next checks if the directory is world-writable, which it is not, so it denies access.

The simplest way to solve this is to make admin the owner of this directory.

Run this command:

```
sudo chown -R admin:admin /var/repo/site.git
```